# FB and LinkedIn APIs are not working in private window mode-FF

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox, facebook-javascript-sdk, linkedin-api

System is not able to access LinkedIn and Facebook JS APIs in private window mode of Firefox, it is breaking and throwing following exceptions;

For Linkedin:

```
 ReferenceError: IN is not defined
```

For Facebook:

```
 ReferenceError: FB is not defined
```

In normal mode it is working fine, even in incognito mode of Chrome this works.

What should I do to make them work?

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn *Tracking Protection* off.

---

Firefox considers the Facebook JS SDK to be a “tracker” script – justifiably so IMHO, because we’ve all read how much data Facebook is collecting, even for not logged in users. And since so many sites use their SDK, the “reach” of their tracking is quite extensive as well.
And with the LinkedIn SDK it is just the same.

Comment: thanks CBroe ... yeah i got the same .... I read this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Privacy/Tracking_Protection .... and it is saying the same thing. :)

Comment: This is fine and dandy, but I'm getting the same problem. Yet...go to nike.com and it works. Why does theirs work?